# Date interpretation in tsx is wrong with years like 0022

Tags: typescript, date, input

I've a problem with dates in tsx. The problem is that If I set a date like this 30/11/0022, it interpret the date as 30/11/1922. And that is wrong.

I've this input element in tsx:

```
<FormikField name="Birthdate" disabled={FormState.loading}/>
```

Which FormikField comes from here, this definition:

```
interface Props {
  name: string;
  autoFocus?: boolean;
  hidden?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
  component?: React.Component;
  label?: string;
  className?: string;
  disableAutocomplete?: boolean; 
}

export const FormikField = ({ ...props }: Props) => {
  const [field] = useField(props.name);
  const { errors, setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();

  const fieldprops = FormFields[props.name] ?? FormFields.Default;
  const thiserror = getIn(errors, props.name);

  const [passwordType, setPasswordType] = useState(true);
  const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false);
  const [empty, setEmpty] = useState(field.value === '');

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (fieldprops.type === 'password') {
      setPasswordType(!passwordType);
    }
  };

  const handleFocus = () => {
    setFocus(!focus);
    setEmpty(field.value === '');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (field.value !== '') {
      setFocus(true);
    }
  }, [field.value]);

  return (
    <FormWrapper className={props.className}>
      <FormWrapperInput error={thiserror ? true : false} disabled={props.disabled} focus={focus || !empty}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor={props.name}>{props.label ? props.label : fieldprops.placeholder}</label>
          <input
            type={fieldprops.type === 'password' ? (passwordType ? 'password' : 'text') : fieldprops.type}
            autoFocus={props.autoFocus}
            {...field}
            {...props}
            onFocus={handleFocus}
            onBlur={handleFocus}
            autoComplete={props.disableAutocomplete !== undefined && props.disableAutocomplete ? 'new-password' : 'on'} 
          />
          {fieldprops.type === 'password' ? (
            <div onClick={handleClick} className="FormIcon">
              {passwordType ? <AiOutlineEye /> : <AiOutlineEyeInvisible />}
            </div>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}
        </div>
      </FormWrapperInput>
      <ErrorMessage name={props.name} component={FormError} />
    </FormWrapper>
  );
};
```

So the Birthday type is define here:

```
Birthdate:{
        type: 'date',
        defaultvalue: null,
        placeholder: 'Set your birthday',
        validations: yup.date()
                        .required('The field is needed')
                        .min(new Date(new Date().getFullYear() - 120, new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate()), 
                            'The birthday can not be more than 120 years')
                        .max(new Date(new Date().getFullYear() - 1, new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate()),
                            'The birthday can not be less than 1 year.')
    }
```

Is there something I can do tho avoid this? Take care that I'm using getFullYear()

Answer (score 0):

Formik doesn't really have native date support (and generally speaking is increasingly unsupported). Formik's default `onChange` handler will look for the `e.target.value` property, which even on a `type="date"` input, will be a *string*.

This is where things start to go wrong as now you are storing a string representation in form state which is far more ambiguous than a real date object. At some point, this string is likely being converted back to a date. This would be when JS's default date parsing kicks in which notably has some peculiarities around dates like the one you mentioned.

It is better to store a date for real in your form state, which can be accessed via `e.target.valueAsDate` in the `onChange` handler.

So we now override `onChange` and check if the field is a date type. If it is, we have some custom code to set the field value to the `valueAsDate`. If it is not, we run the default Formik `onChange` handler.

```
interface Props {
  name: string;
  autoFocus?: boolean;
  hidden?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
  component?: React.Component;
  label?: string;
  className?: string;
  disableAutocomplete?: boolean; 
}

export const FormikField = ({ ...props }: Props) => {
  const [field, meta, helpers] = useField(props.name);
  const { errors, setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();

  const fieldprops = FormFields[props.name] ?? FormFields.Default;
  const thiserror = getIn(errors, props.name);

  const [passwordType, setPasswordType] = useState(true);
  const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false);
  const [empty, setEmpty] = useState(field.value === '');

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (fieldprops.type === 'password') {
      setPasswordType(!passwordType);
    }
  };

  const handleFocus = () => {
    setFocus(!focus);
    setEmpty(field.value === '');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (field.value !== '') {
      setFocus(true);
    }
  }, [field.value]);

  return (
    <FormWrapper className={props.className}>
      <FormWrapperInput error={thiserror ? true : false} disabled={props.disabled} focus={focus || !empty}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor={props.name}>{props.label ? props.label : fieldprops.placeholder}</label>
          <input
            type={fieldprops.type === 'password' ? (passwordType ? 'password' : 'text') : fieldprops.type}
            autoFocus={props.autoFocus}
            {...field}
            {...props}
            onChange={(e) => {
              if (fieldprops.type === 'date') {
                  helpers.setValue(e.target.valueAsDate)
                  return
              }

              field.onChange(e)
            }}
            onFocus={handleFocus}
            onBlur={handleFocus}
            autoComplete={props.disableAutocomplete !== undefined && props.disableAutocomplete ? 'new-password' : 'on'} 
          />
          {fieldprops.type === 'password' ? (
            <div onClick={handleClick} className="FormIcon">
              {passwordType ? <AiOutlineEye /> : <AiOutlineEyeInvisible />}
            </div>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}
        </div>
      </FormWrapperInput>
      <ErrorMessage name={props.name} component={FormError} />
    </FormWrapper>
  );
};
```